# how to calculate total distance traveled by a bullet with 2 ricochets in python

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

I am trying to find the optimal way to calculate the total distance a bullet traveled in a room.
consider a co-ordinate axis with dimensions given. There are co-ordinates of 2 points given say A and B. Now **A** shoots **B** in a way that bullet take 2 ricochets(2 hits at corners of wall) before hitting **B** .

I attached an image describing the situation[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSoPu.png). The red line in the image shows the path of bullet.

Now how to calculate the distance traveled by the bullet optimal way.

[image]

Comment: So basically path finding?

Comment: Way too vague dude. Do we know the angle relative to the ground that the bullet is shot at? Do we know how far away from the wall that the bullet is shot at? Do we know how tall the ceiling is? ..

Comment: it is just in 2-Dimensions. knowing angle makes the problem easy. There is no angle given but the room dimensions will be given along with co-ordinates of A and B.

Comment: @Octo I dont need the path, but i want only the total distance from A to B.

Comment: @PeterWood i'm sorry. I didnt get you.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your image

[image]

now the red lines are just hypoteneuses for your right triangles 
sum the hypotenueses and you solve the problem ... at least thats one way to solve

```
a**2 + b**2 = c**2 #use this equation to solve hypoteneuses
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but i feel there must be more efficient way to solve this problem which i could'nt come with.